# Exporting COM+ Component via command line?

Tags: com+, dcom

I'm trying to automate the creation of a COM+ Application proxy. Normally we go through the Component Services and use the wizard to create the MSI for the client side installation, but I would like to be able to automate the creation so that it can be pushed out to clients and installed via script. How can I accomplish this?